# Sort Function to Include Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a function that sorts divs numerically based on class however it is not assuming children when it grabs the data. Here is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var sortedDivs = $(".frame").find("div").toArray().sort(sorter);
  $.each(sortedDivs, function (index, value) {
    $(".sorted").append(value);
  });
});

function sorter(a, b) {
     return a.getAttribute('class') - b.getAttribute('class');
};
```

It takes this:

```
<div class="frame">
<div class="5">
   Div 5 here
   <div class="sub">
        Div 11 here             
   </div>
</div> 
<div class="3"> 
   Div 3 Here 
</div> 
<div class="4.5"> 
   Div 4.5 here 
</div>
<div class="4">
  Div 4 Here
</div>
```

And outputs:

```
<div class="frame"></div>
<div class="sorted">
  <div class="sub">
     Div 11 here             
  </div>
  <div class="3"> 
     Div 3 Here 
  </div>
  <div class="4">
    Div 4 Here
  </div>
  <div class="4.5"> 
    Div 4.5 here 
  </div>
  <div class="5">
    Div 5 here  
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the script to also move all children (i.e. div, img, etc.) and thereby place "Div 11 here" last. In other words, `.sub` would remain a child of `.5`.

Any great ideas? =D

See Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/6hpNz/65/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector to

```
var sortedDivs = $(".frame>div").toArray().sort(sorter);
```

[Refer updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hpNz/67/)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the selector to this:

```
var sortedDivs = $(".frame > div").toArray().sort(sorter);
```

it will take all the divs under the `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all divs from `.frame` so it includes `div with 11` also. Just find children of `.frame`

```
var sortedDivs = $(".frame").children().toArray().sort(sorter);
```